# How can I update all settings fields by key field in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a database table named `settings`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `settings` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `value` text NOT NULL,
   `type` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

This is my model to get any field:

```
<?php

class Settings_model extends CI_Model{
    /*
     * Get global settings
    */
    public function get_global_settings() {
      $query  = $this->db->get('settings');
      $result = $query->result();
      return $result;
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
// Loop to get all settings in the 'globals' table
foreach($this->Settings_model->get_global_settings() as $result) {
  $this->global_data[$result->key] = $result->value;
}
```

Now, how can I update all table fields in same page using foreach?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors are you getting from those attempts?

Comment: Can you please give more clarification

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you are trying to populate an html table, if so consider loading the view in your controller, sending $this->global_data as parameter

```
$this->load->view('view', $this->global_data);
```

Now the table in the view file

```
<table
   <?php foreach($global_data as $data){?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $data->value1;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->value2;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data->value3;?></td>
      </tr>
 <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use codeigniter 'update_batch' to update all records. For example,

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'key' => 'name' ,
      'value' => 'My Name'
   ),
   array(
      'key' => 'organisation' ,
      'value' => 'My Organisation' 
   )
);


$this->db->update_batch('settings', $data, 'key');
```

The above code will generate query like this,

```
UPDATE `settings` SET `value` = CASE
 WHEN `key` = 'name' THEN 'My Name '
 WHEN `key` = 'organisation' THEN 'My Organisation'
 ELSE `value` END,
 WHERE `key` IN ('name','organisation');
```